# WordPress: don't show 404 when no posts exist

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Currently there is a bug in WordPress if you have a Posts Page set under:

> Settings->Reading->A Static Page->Posts Page

If there are posts, than the page (e.g. with a slug called `news`) displays the post, and uses `index.php` from the theme.

But, with this configuration, if there are no posts, then it calls the theme's `404` page.  This is definitely a bug, and has been submitted ([Ticket #10822](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10822)).  It should be letting `index.php` show whatever it wants upon `!have_posts()`, but right now the page doesn't seem to be called at all.

My question is: is there a workaround for this bug **without modifying core wp files**?  I'd be open to a plugin, theme changes, a custom page template, htaccess changes, etc.

Comment: Surely this should be on Superuser?

Comment: No... I'm not asking for help with a simple configuration of WordPress. There's obviously a coding issue here and I've got no problem writing custom PHP in themes or plugin so long as it doesn't override core files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just performed a test for it.  It isn't actually serving a 404, it's using index.php but since no posts are found so it falls outside of the have_posts().  Are you sure it's not a plugin or theme causing your issue?  I tested this with the default theme on a base install of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Most theme files have as part of their WP loop a catch for no posts, i.e.:

```
<?php else : ?>
Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

That might be what you're seeing. You can use a custom page template without that text (leave the loop) for yoiur posts page. And try   [Reveal Template | coffee2code.com](http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/reveal-template/) to find out what template file you're looking at.

Comment: No I've confirmed that the text that is showing up is the text of my 404.php, not the text that show in the `else` block after `if (have_posts())`.